# tuple object has no attribute 'stripe_customer_key in webhook

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

hi iam tring to process a stripe webhook when i run into this issue

> AttributeError: tuple object has no attribute 'stripe_customer_key

my code is:

```
dash_user.stripe_customer_key = event_json['data']['object']['subscriptions']['data'][0]['customer']
```

Comment: check your attribute by printing `dash_user.__dict__` on the console.

Answer (score 1):

Please share a bit more of your code. What is `dash_user`? Is it a dict? If it is, you should do

```
dash_user['stripe_customer_key']
```